# Excel formula to compare dates between three columns

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have ran into a roadblock with a spreadsheet that i am building.  The section i need help with will be 3 columns containing dates.  Below is what im trying to do. Condional Formatting will be applied to Column “C”

If “A1” or “B1” are blank then ignore it, but if “A1” or “B1” has a date, then compare the dates to the date in “C1” and if either “A1” or “B1” are Greater Than “C1” then “C1” should turn RED

Answer (score 0):

> Your conditional formatting rule will be `MAX(A1:B1) > C1`.

You don't need to check if they are blank using this route. These will be evaluated as `0` by the `MAX` function. When this is compared to an actual date, it will surely be less than your value in `C1` assuming it is a valid date

---

[[image]
[image]

Comment: I am also trying to do another conditional formatting in the same spreadsheet. to apply to Column S.                                     If $S2 date is expired then turn red but if $R2 is blank then do nothing.